# How to modify the DOM from inside a Meteor package

Tags: meteor

I need to remove a class to a `<div>` from inside a meteor package, but the following code doesn't work:

```js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    $('div').removeClass('class-to-remove');
  });
}
```

The documentation says:

> On a client, startup callbacks from packages will be called first, followed by  templates from your .html files, followed by your application code.

There is a way to modify the DOM from inside a package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried vanilla JS code instead of jQuery?

```
document.getElementById('divId').classList.remove('class-to-remove');
```

**EDIT: New sample attached:**

Let's say we have this template markup:

```html
<template name="appBody">
  <div id="myCustomDiv" class="I-will-stay-here I-will-be-removed-by-package">
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

> Create a custom js file under the package ( /lib for example) and add your DOM manipulation code there e.G:
>   **[project root]/packages/[your package]/lib/my-custom.js**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.body.rendered = function() {
        $('#myCustomDiv').removeClass ('I-will-be-removed-by-package');
    };
};
```

In your **package.js** make sure that you have following **api.use** configurations:

```
 api.use(['jquery','templating','spacebars','blaze','ui'], 'client');
 api.addFiles('/lib/my-custom.js','client');
```

[Working sample I've done on github to showcase the solution](https://github.com/meteorpoly/sof-custom-dom-sample.git)

Comment: Mayby just stating the obvious here, but the line "Template.body.rendered" should be "Template.appBody.rendered = function(){...} since the template is named "appBody" and not "body". That should definitely work.

Comment: @cfs the package is not aware of any appBody template on startup. template.body is a generic template object from api.use(['templating',...],'').